# Group results into sections by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to figure out how to group results into different sections by date.

I have a page that has reservations with different dates, instead of having a table sorted by dates, I want to create each reservation in its own section on that date.

ex.

```
January 27

John Doe - 01/27/17
Jane doe - 01/27/17
```

---

```
January 28
Ricky Bobby - 01/28/17
```

---

```
January 29
Baby Jesus - 01/29/17
```

Comment: Where are you getting the date values from? Are you iterating over an activerecord relation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the date values are from activerecord and outputted into a table. I need to split the dates into separate tables.

DiegoSalazar, understandable that my question isn't very indepth but it is straight to the point. I need to separate data by date value while grouping the results. Seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_by` on a collection of dates, then pass in a [method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-yday) like `.month` or `.yday`

```
array = [Date.today, Date.today, Date.today.next, Date.new(2017,12,31)]
array.group_by(&:yday)
```

This returns the list of dates by the day in the year. Its basically equivalent to `Hash[yday] = Array.new(matching_dates)`.

Comment: okay, so i am still new to ruby on rails but i do understand how this is working but i am having the issue of grabbing my data by the dates. I am calling my model with a .all, which gives me all the information in that model. I was thinking that I need to group it by pu_time (which is datetime in my model).

Comment: I figured it out by using the group_by, a good example of what I was looking for was from [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month)